# How to pass value stored in browser local storage to browser initiated request?

Tags: javascript

I have stored value in browser local storage

```
window.localStroage.setItem(key,'value-x');
```

How would i pass 'value-x' in custom request header? [using Javascript]
e.g need to pass stored value with image request.

```
<img src="some/url" />
```

How to set custom header with 'value-x' in 'some/url' request (which is initiated by browser)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The only time you can set an HTTP header programmatically is when you are making a request from JavaScript via XMLHttpRequest or fetch. There's no way to do it when the request is made by the insertion of an `<img>` element.

The closest you could come here would be to make the request using XHR, convert the response into a `data:` scheme URI, and then populate the `src` attribute with that.